# Issue with Redux Toolkit and Server-Side Rendering in Next.js: Hydration Error and 'useContext' Problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

**Hello Stack Overflow Community!**

I'm new to Stack Overflow and this is my first question. Unfortunately, I'm facing a problem that I couldn't find a solution for, and it's been quite frustrating.

I'm currently working on an e-commerce project that involves two web apps, one of which is an admin dashboard. My tech stack includes Next.js 13.4.5, TypeScript, Prisma, MongoDB, Redux Toolkit, Axios, and some other packages. You can check out my installed npm packages here:

- [My npm packages. Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hrYB.png)
- [My npm packages. Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N09Kd.png)

The issue I'm facing is related to Redux Toolkit, and it's causing the following errors:

1. "Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."
2. "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')."
3. "Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering."

Here's the relevant code snippets:

**slices/apiSlice.ts:**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '' });

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery,
    tagTypes: ['User'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({})
});
```

**slices/authSlice.ts**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const getUserInfo = typeof window !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('userInfo');

const initialState = {
    userInfo: getUserInfo ? JSON.parse(getUserInfo) : null
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setCredentials: (state, action) => {
            state.userInfo = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(action.payload))
        },
        logout: (state, action: { payload: any } = { payload: null }) => {
            state.userInfo = action.payload;
            localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
        }
    }
});

export const { setCredentials, logout } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**slices/ApiSlice.ts**

```
import { apiSlice } from "@/slices/apiSlice";
const USERS_URL = '/api/users';

export const usersApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        login: builder.mutation({
            query: (data) => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/sign-in`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            })
        }),
        logout: builder.mutation({
            query: () => ({
                url: `${USERS_URL}/logout`,
                method: 'POST',
            })
        })
    })
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useLogoutMutation } = usersApiSlice;
```

**lib/store.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from '@/slices/authSlice';
import { apiSlice } from '@/slices/apiSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
    devTools: true
});

export default store;
```

**app/layout.tsx**

```
"use client"
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

import { ModalProvider } from '@/providers/modal-provider';
import { ToastProvider } from '@/providers/toast-provider';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@/providers/theme-provider';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '@/lib/store';

import './globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export default async function RootLayout(params: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="system"
            enableSystem
          >
            <ToastProvider />
            <ModalProvider />
            {params && params.children ? params.children : null}
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};
```

**components/modals/user-modal.tsx**

```
'use client';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useLoginMutation } from '@/slices/usersApiSlice';
import { setCredentials } from '@/slices/authSlice';

import { Modal } from '@/components/ui/modal';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { useUserModal } from '@/hooks/use-user-modal';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const formSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().min(3).max(24),
  password: z.string().min(8).max(32),
});

export const UserModal = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    },
  });

  const pathname = usePathname();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [login] = useLoginMutation();

  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state: any) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname === '/' && userInfo) {
      return window.location.assign('/overviews');
    }
  }, [pathname, userInfo])
  
  const userModal = useUserModal();
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await login(values).unwrap();
      dispatch(setCredentials({ ...response.user }));
      window.location.assign('/overviews')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && error);
      toast.error('Something went wrong');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      title="Login"
      description="Login to manage products and categories."
      isOpen={userInfo ? false : userModal.isOpen}
      onClose={userModal.onClose}
    >
      <div>
        <div className="space-y-4 py-2 pb-4">
          <div className="space-y-2">
            <Form {...form}>
              <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="username"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input
                          disabled={loading}
                          placeholder="username123"
                          {...field}
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
                <br />
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="password"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input
                          disabled={loading}
                          placeholder="pass123word"
                          {...field}
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
                <div className="pt-6 space-x-2 flex items-center justify-end w-full">
                  <Button
                    disabled={loading}
                    variant="outline"
                    onClick={userModal.onClose}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    disabled={loading}
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Continue
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

I've been troubleshooting this issue for a while, but I'm not making much progress. I would appreciate any ideas or solutions you can provide.

Thank you for taking the time to help a newcomer to Stack Overflow!

**P.S.**: I used ChatGPT to help me craft this question, so if anything seems unclear or if you need more details, please let me know. Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

**What I Tried:**

I tried stopping the code and starting it again, thinking that might fix the problem. But it didn't work.

I also looked on Stack Overflow for answers because it's a good place for help with tech stuff. Sadly, I couldn't find any solutions related to my issue.

**What I Expected vs. What Happened:**

I thought that if I stopped and started the code, it would start working as it should. But, to my disappointment, it didn't.

I was hoping to find answers on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find anything that matched my problem. It's been a bit frustrating not to find a solution. Any help or ideas would be really appreciated.